# Homework Help - Object-Oriented Programming

Tags: python, class, oop, debugging, object

In my intro class, we just started the section on object-oriented programming. This class is the first I've ever been exposed to programming, and I'm really not understanding it.

We have an assignment where we have to create an Animal class, a Zoo class, and then a zookeeper program to run the information from the first two classes. I have the programs typed up based off of examples in my book, but am still not doing it correctly.

If you could look over my codes and give me some feedback or help, that would be greatly appreciated!

```
    class Animal:
        def __innit__(self, animal_type, name):
            self.animal_type = animal_type
            self.name = name
        def get_animal_type(self, animal_type):
            self.__animal_type = animal_type
        def get_name(self, name):
            self.__name = name
        def check_mood(self, mood):
            input random.txt
            print random.random()

    Class Zoo:
        def __innit__(self):
            self.__animals = animal_list
        def add_animals(self, animal):
            self.__animals.append(animal)
        def show_animals(animal_list):
            return animal_list

    input Animal.py
    input Zoo.py
    def main():
        ADD_ANIMAL = 1
        SHOW_ANIMALS = 2
        EXIT = 3
        def get_manu_choice():
            print()
            print("Zoo Options")
            print("-----------")
            print("1. Add Animal")
            print("2. Show Animals")
            print("3. Exit")
            print()
        choice = int(input("What would you like to do? "))
        while choice < ADD_ANIMAL or choice > EXIT:
            choice = int(input("Please choose a valid option: "))
        return choice
    main()
```

Comment: I apologize for no homework help tag, I don't have the reputation to do it so far, apparently.

Comment: You had typo in your question `innit`. Please fix that in your program

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out! Totally missed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **innit** should be **init**

Looks to me like you are missing a chunk of functionality. You need an instance of zoo, and then in response to the input, either add another animal to the zoo or print the list of animals.